# Dynamic Variable in md-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can I make the Dynamic Tab with label in `md-tab-group` ?

```
        <md-tab-group>
            <md-tab label="ABC"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="DEF"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="xyz"></md-tab>
        </md-tab-group>
```

I want to make tab name hardy when hardy logins and this should be on right part of screen and a with a logout icon so that user can logout eaisly.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, definitely. Can you explain more what you want to do? like by a button click and a new tab comes out?

Comment: @CharlieNg I have edit my question can you check it please

Comment: Just create a field and bind it in the component template.

Comment: can you do something like this? add one more md-tab, and use ng-if to control if the user has logged in? <md-tab ng-if="isUserLoggedIn" label="hardy"></md-tab>

Comment: Do you want it to be hard coded as "hardy"?

Comment: @CharlieNg let say now charlie come i need charlie their .. That's what dynamic means. you are going for one condition

Comment: You will have a way to get the login id, right? just do  <md-tab ng-if="isUserLoggedIn" label="{{loginId}}"></md-tab>

Comment: @ecain no i need DYNAMIC if any user will come then his name came on tab top-right corner.

Comment: Do what Charlie suggested.

Comment: Though if this is Angular not AngularJS it's `*ngIf` not `ng-if`

Comment: @CharlieNg thanks it works but now i am not able to use property like  class="push-right"  to make it on right-top corner can you please suggest for alignment.

Comment: Why would you not be able to use a `class`?

Comment: @ecain i don't know . the class is not effecting that dynamic tab part.

Comment: I can try to update a plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for how you can handle this shown below

```html
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="{{loggedIn}}"></md-tab>
  <md-tab [label]="loggedIn"></md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QwOXYnEc4bAX4U4j0Pak?p=preview)

Comment: thanks . but i need to make alignments as class="pull-right" but it is not effecting.can you please suggest me something.

Comment: that looks like a new question, you should post it with the relevant code